# Auto pop up Einstein chat window

Tags: einstein, popup-window

Is it possible to pop up Einstein chat window(with a welcome message) in a web site (page load)  with out clicking "Chat with an expert" button.

Answer (score 0):

I've not implemented this myself but if you are looking to open the chatbot on a webpage directly without having to click a Chat button,you can make use of Bootstrap Embedded Chat function
`embedded_svc.bootstrapEmbeddedService(attributes);`

From [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/embedded_services_web_bootstrap_chat.htm),

> This API provides developers with a quick Chat setup that skips the static help button stage, loading all the necessary dependencies, bootstraps, and opens the chat application on your website with one call.

> The result of using this API is the same for a customer clicking the standard "Chat With an Expert" button. If you have pre-chat enabled, it surfaces the pre-chat form. If you’ve disabled pre-chat, it sends a chat request and surface the waiting state.

It should also be possible to set it up such that you can bypass the prechat window and the chatbot directly greets the customer by name and starts conversation. You can use the 'embedded_svc.settings.prepopulatedPrechatFields' to prepopulate the name, email ID

To pass the context information without opening the pre-chat window try something like

```
embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
"label":"First Name",
"name":"FirstName",
"value":"Jane",
"displayToAgent":true
}];
```

"Jane" would have to be replaced with your variable for the actual name.